# Sublime Text 3 Typescript Plugin Error

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

The console prints out the following error. This happens on every keystroke in an ts file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\listeners\idle.py",  line 22, in _check_timeout_count self.handler()
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\listeners\idle.py", line 79, in on_selection_idle self.request_document_highlights(view, info)
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\listeners\idle.py", line 187, in request_document_highlights    cli.service.async_document_highlights(view.file_name(), location, self.highlight_occurrences)
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\libs\service_proxy.py", line 259, in async_document_highlights
self.__comm.sendCmdAsync(json_str, on_completed, req_dict["seq"])
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\libs\node_client.py", line 111, in sendCmdAsync
if self.postCmd(cmd):
File "C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\libs\node_client.py", line 143, in postCmd
self.server_proc.stdin.flush()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

This happens on every keystroke in a typescript file.

```
reloading plugin VAlign.valign
reloading plugin HTML-CSS-JS Prettify.HTMLPrettify
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.ordereddict
reloading plugin SublimeCodeIntel.SublimeCodeIntel
plugins loaded
Package Control: The package TypeScript is being re-enabled after a Package     Control operation was interrupted
ignored packages updated to: ["Vintage"]
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-04-21  07:13:35, next run at 2016-04-21 08:13:35 or after
reloading plugin TypeScript.main
2016-04-21 08:12:36,324: 3912: INFO: Logging configured to log to file:   C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\typescript\TS.log
2016-04-21 08:12:36,362: 3912: WARNING: TypeScript plugin initialized.
lang_service_enabled: True
Path of tsserver.js: C:\Sublime  Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\tsserver\tsserver.js
Path of tsc.js: C:\Sublime Text\Data\Packages\TypeScript\tsserver\tsc.js
Path of node executable is configured as: C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe
Trying to spawn node executable from: C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe
generating syntax summary
generating meta info summary
reloading /C/Sublime Text/Data/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
reloading Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Packages/TypeScript/popup.html
+ Info: processing None': please wait...
Could not import subprocess32 module, falling back to subprocess module
```

Any advice?

Comment: you should check/report this on the [official issues list](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues)

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/143)

Comment: @KeithHall thx. i wrote a report on the official issues list.

Comment: @idleberg i tried it with a new installed sublime and typescript. there where no leftovers or anything. and i am using a portable version too and i am getting the same error.